# ClassNotFound exception when I generate aar file

Tags: android, android-library

I have a libray project. When i use it as module it works fine with my applicaion.

```
compile project(':myLib')
```

When I use the generated aar file, no error on compilation, but while running it gives the class not found exception. Any idea how to solve this?

```
compile(name:':myLib', ext:'aar')
```